# How to make QGIS 3.18 display Chinese characters in labels

Tags: qgis, maptiler, chinese

I am using vector tiles from Maptiler in QGIS 3.18. I have set the language of the tiles to Chinese on the maptiler website. The labels display in QGIS in Pinyin (romanization of Chinese characters.) I need to see the actual characters. Actually the ideal situation would be English and Chinese side by side (this is the expected behavior based on the maptiler preview map) but I would settle for just Chinese characters.